# Is there a good reason for setting up virtualenv for python in Docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv

Almost all python tutorials suggest that virutalenv be setup as step one to maintain consistency . In working with Docker containers, why or why not should this standard be maintained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to run only one version on the container and it is the container's system version, there's no technical reason to use virtualenv in a container. But there could still be non-technical reasons. For example, if your team is used to finding python libraries in ~/some-env, or understands the virtualenv structure better than the container's libs, then you may want to keep using virtualenv anyway.

On the "cons" side, virtualenv on top of an existing system python may make your images slightly larger, too.

Answer (score 1):

When using docker it makes sense to adopt the microservices concept. With microservices each microservice is aligned with a specific business function, and only defines the operations necessary to that business function. This means that each application runs in one or more separate docker images with their specific dependencies (python modules). This makes the use of virtualenv unnecessary.